# How to organize a character chronically by Date in R?

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
  Group.1   a_VidP   b_VidP   w_VidP   h_VidP   n_VidP
1  01/2019 84.61538       NA 92.59259 90.90909       NA
2  01/2020 92.30769 57.14286 93.78330       NA       NA
3  02/2019 85.71429       NA 95.03916 83.33333       NA
4  02/2020       NA 61.53846 93.79433 96.00000       NA
5  03/2019       NA 85.71429 91.28205 88.23529       NA
6  03/2020 81.44750 66.19171 73.78146 78.31021       NA
7  04/2019       NA       NA 94.13265 92.85714       NA
8  04/2020 88.51629 77.38986 78.78385 85.03030 66.66667
9  05/2019       NA       NA 96.88385 90.47619       NA
10 05/2020 91.28368 80.08889 80.90315 87.39603       NA
```

I would like to organize the df chronologically by Group.1. Right now, Group.1 is a class "character". I want to transform it to a date and then order the rows in chronological order so that the output is:

```
   Group.1   a_VidP   b_VidP   w_VidP   h_VidP   n_VidP
1  01/2019 84.61538       NA 92.59259 90.90909       NA
2  02/2019 85.71429       NA 95.03916 83.33333       NA
3  03/2019       NA 85.71429 91.28205 88.23529       NA
4  04/2019       NA       NA 94.13265 92.85714       NA
5  05/2019       NA       NA 96.88385 90.47619       NA
6  01/2020 92.30769 57.14286 93.78330       NA       NA
7  02/2020       NA 61.53846 93.79433 96.00000       NA
8  03/2020 81.44750 66.19171 73.78146 78.31021       NA
9  04/2020 88.51629 77.38986 78.78385 85.03030 66.66667
10 05/2020 91.28368 80.08889 80.90315 87.39603       NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `lubridate::my` (month-year) to convert to date, combined with `arrange`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

data %>% arrange(lubridate::my(Group.1))

   Group.1   a_VidP   b_VidP   w_VidP   h_VidP   n_VidP
1  01/2019 84.61538       NA 92.59259 90.90909       NA
2  02/2019 85.71429       NA 95.03916 83.33333       NA
3  03/2019       NA 85.71429 91.28205 88.23529       NA
4  04/2019       NA       NA 94.13265 92.85714       NA
5  05/2019       NA       NA 96.88385 90.47619       NA
6  01/2020 92.30769 57.14286 93.78330       NA       NA
7  02/2020       NA 61.53846 93.79433 96.00000       NA
8  03/2020 81.44750 66.19171 73.78146 78.31021       NA
9  04/2020 88.51629 77.38986 78.78385 85.03030 66.66667
10 05/2020 91.28368 80.08889 80.90315 87.39603       NA
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `"01/"` into beginning of `Group.1` and convert them to date.

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(Group.1 = as.Date(paste0("01/", Group.1), format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  arrange(Group.1)
#>       Group.1   a_VidP   b_VidP   w_VidP   h_VidP   n_VidP
#> 1  2019-01-01 84.61538       NA 92.59259 90.90909       NA
#> 2  2019-02-01 85.71429       NA 95.03916 83.33333       NA
#> 3  2019-03-01       NA 85.71429 91.28205 88.23529       NA
#> 4  2019-04-01       NA       NA 94.13265 92.85714       NA
#> 5  2019-05-01       NA       NA 96.88385 90.47619       NA
#> 6  2020-01-01 92.30769 57.14286 93.78330       NA       NA
#> 7  2020-02-01       NA 61.53846 93.79433 96.00000       NA
#> 8  2020-03-01 81.44750 66.19171 73.78146 78.31021       NA
#> 9  2020-04-01 88.51629 77.38986 78.78385 85.03030 66.66667
#> 10 2020-05-01 91.28368 80.08889 80.90315 87.39603       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

`dput` of data

```r
data <- structure(list(Group.1 = c("01/2019", "01/2020", "02/2019", "02/2020", 
  "03/2019", "03/2020", "04/2019", "04/2020", "05/2019", "05/2020"
), a_VidP = c(84.61538, 92.30769, 85.71429, NA, NA, 81.4475, 
  NA, 88.51629, NA, 91.28368), b_VidP = c(NA, 57.14286, NA, 61.53846, 
    85.71429, 66.19171, NA, 77.38986, NA, 80.08889), w_VidP = c(92.59259, 
      93.7833, 95.03916, 93.79433, 91.28205, 73.78146, 94.13265, 78.78385, 
      96.88385, 80.90315), h_VidP = c(90.90909, NA, 83.33333, 96, 88.23529, 
        78.31021, 92.85714, 85.0303, 90.47619, 87.39603), n_VidP = c(NA, 
          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 66.66667, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
            -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

***Updated: Fix the typos errors that cause the incorrect output.***

Comment: Sorry my bad in previous run that got the parenthesis wrong. just fixed!